# What is the difference between Mutah marriage and Misyar marriage?

Tags: nikah, shia-sunni, nikah-al-mutah

I know we have two kinds of marriages in Shia jurisprudence and also two kinds in Sunni jurisprudence.  The ruling of permanent Nikah is similar in five sects (Shia and Sunni). But I want to know the differences between [Nikah Mut'ah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikah_mut%E2%80%98ah) (in Shia jurisprudence) and [Nikah Misyar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikah_Misyar) (in Sunni jurisprudence).

Please show me in what kind of sources (Quran, Sunnah, etc.) we find the legality of two this kinds of marriage.

Answer (score 5):

### Nikah Misyar

This marriage is a normal Islamic marriage with the exception that the husband and wife give up several rights by their own free will, such as living together, equal division of nights between wives in cases of polygyny, the wife's rights to housing, and maintenance money ("nafaqa"), and the husband's right of homekeeping, and access etc. and it is practiced by sunnis.

These rights are not considered obligatory for the marriage contract to happen according to Islam.

Also, Misyar is not temporary. If the marriage is fixed (temporary) then this is haram according to Sunnis.

Last point, Majority of scholars disallowed Misyar marriage, such as Yusuf al-Qaradwai and al-albani and other. Source - Wikipedia - [Criticism of Misyar marriage](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikah_Misyar#Criticism_of_misyar)

---

### Mutah Marriage:

It is a type of marriage used in Twelver Shia sec, where the duration of the marriage and the dowry must be specified and agreed upon in advance.

Moreover, A declaration of the intent to marry and an acceptance of the terms are required (as they are in nikah (marriage in Islam).

---

### In conclusion:

**Misyar** is not a temporary marriage while **Muta'ah** is a temporary marriage.

**For more Info:** *Check the questions tagged with Mutah tag.*

Comment: Off-topic comment: [To be very specific, I would discourage editing a post solely to remove salutations like “hi” and “thanks”. That’s just adding an unnecessary edit on top of an unnecessary set of salutations.](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/107/3487). This [e.g.](http://islam.stackexchange.com/revisions/16742/2). Please, try to refrain from it.

Answer (score 0):

The majority of the scholars agree on misyar based on its validity, but they still discourage it due to the social problems that may arise.