# Is there any way I can do a temporary marriage in a halal way?

Tags: nikah, sex

There is a girl that I really want to have intercourse with. However, I don’t think we are at the stage to marry permanently. Is there a way temporary marriage can be done in a halal way?

Comment: The relevant term is Nikah mut'ah, and Sunni Islam does not allow it.

Comment: A marriage with the intention of talaq is haram in Sunni Islam.

Answer (score 2):

Temporary marriage or Nikah Mut'ah (literally translating to 'pleasure marriage') is forbidden:

> "Ali said to Ibn'Abbas, may Allah be please with them both: The Prophet forbade Mut'ah marriage, and the flesh of domesticated donkeys on the Day of Khaibar."' (Sahih, [Sunan an-Nasa'i](https://sunnah.com/nasai/42/72))

Sunni Islam forbids temporary marriages for pleasure, so you should either marry a person for good with the intention of a full marriage or fast to supress your desires.

Likewise Zaidi Shias, Ismaili Shias, and Dawoodi Bohras all consider it forbidden because Ali (RA) reported the Prophet (SAW) forbidding it.

On the other hand, Twelver Shia consider Nikah Mut'ah permissible, because they do not accept the above hadith, and they use the verse 4:24.

All in all, Sunnis are in agreement that it is forbidden and Shias are divided on the matter.

Comment: This is biased. Although as a Sunni Muslim I agree with you, some Shia practise Nikah Mut'ah and therefore regard it as permissible. Answers should contain different views on the subject with evidence for both views.

Comment: I’ve just done some more research and found something called Nikah misyar. Is this form allowed?

Comment: @Bilal.Ali . It is a controversial thing and many Sunni scholars consider it to be Zinah and/or against Islamic Law.

Comment: @Bilal.Ali [This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16507/what-is-the-difference-between-mutah-marriage-and-misyar-marriage) should help you understand what both types of Nikah are.